# All combination of size k with conditions

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, combinations

I am stuck on this problem for days:

I'm trying to get combinations of an integer vector on C++ but with conditions, which would allow me to calculate much larger combinations.  For example :

- Let a vector N = [1,2,3,4] (so here n = 4) and k = 2
- And conditions in the form of a map (int - > vector) :
- 1 -> [3]
- 2 - > [4]
- 3 -> [1,4]
- 4 -> [2,3]

Here it means that 1 can not be with 3 in a combination, 2 not with 4, 3 not with 1 and 4 and so on...

For k = 2, we get :

- [1,2]
- [1,4]
- [2,3]

At the moment, I am computing all the combinations and then filtering them, but this for larger n and larger k takes a lot of time. So the idea is to avoid computing combinations that are useless.

Thanks for your help !

### EDIT :

For further clarity:

For n = 4 and k = 2, we have these following combinations:

- 1 2
- 1 3
- 1 4
- 2 3
- 2 4
- 3 4

And be the condition map ( of type map<int,vector<vector> ):
//number: vector of the integers with that it cannot be associated

- 1 : [3]
- 2 : [4]
- 3 : [1,4]
- 4 : [2,3]

But if we take into account the conditions :

- 1 2 -> this combination is valid because 1 cannot be associated with 3, which means it can be associated with 2,3 and 2 cannot be associated with 4 i.e. it can be associated with 1,3.
- 1 3 -> this combination is invalid because 1 cannot be associated with 3.
- 1 4 -> this combination is valid because 1 can be associated with everything except 3.
- 2 3 -> this combination is valid because 2 can be associated with everything but 4.
- 2 4 -> this combination is invalid because 2 cannot be with 4 (and vice versa).
- 3 4 -> this combination is invalid because 3 cannot be with 1 nor with 4.

Hence:

- [1,2]
- [1,4]
- [2,3]

The conditions can also be added between each integer. For k = 3, for example:

- 1 2 4 is an invalid combination because although 1 can be associated with 2 and 4, 2 and 4 cannot be associated.
- The same goes for 1 2 3, because 1 and 3 can not be associated together.

(Besides there is no valid combination for k = 3 here).

I tried this (I use python because it is simpler for me but the solution must be feasible in C++, a pseudo code is more than enough):

```
def ini_comb(arr, ex, n, k):
    
    data = [0]*k
    comb(arr,data,ex,0,n - 1, 0, k)

def comb(arr, data, ex, start, end, index, k):
                        
    if (index == k):

        for j in range(k):
            print(data[j], end = " ")

        print()
        return

    i = start

    while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= k - index):

        test = 1
        data[index] = arr[i]

        for k in data:
            if k:
                for j in ex[k-1]:
                    if j in data:
                        test = 0
                        break
                if not test:
                    break
        
        if test:
            comb(arr,data,ex,i + 1,end,index + 1,k)
        i += 1


arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(arr)
k = 2
ex = [[3],[4],[1,4],[3,2]]
ini_comb(arr,ex,n,k)
```

Here I use a simple recursion to go through all the combinations, and when one of them doesn't meet the conditions of the ex list, then I don't do a recursion with it. But it doesn't work because I only get: [1 2].

### Solution :

Solution:
Here is the solution (in python) for those who will need it ! As suggested by @Jarod42 , I use the backtracking algorithm and before doing the recursion I check the validity of the combination :

```
def p(arr,ex):
    ret = [] 
    def back_track(start_idx, temp,ex):
        ret.append(temp)
        for i in range(start_idx, len(arr)):
            test = 1
            for k in temp + [arr[i]]:
                if k:
                    for j in ex[k-1]:
                        if j in temp + [arr[i]]:
                            test = 0
                            break
                    if not test:
                        break
        
            if test:
                back_track(i + 1, temp + [arr[i]],ex)
    back_track(0, [],ex)
    return ret

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
n = len(arr)
ex = [[4],[5],[5],[1,5,6],[2,3,4,6],[4,5]]

res = p(arr,ex)
res.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

for i in res:
    print(i)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what do you mean by "1 can not be with 3 in a combination, 2 not with 4, 3 not with 1 and 4 and so on..."

Comment: I edited my initial post !

Comment: Look at [Backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). So, you backtrack as soon as you break one condition.

Comment: Ty ! I solve it with this !